# Transform probability density from low to high dimension with Jacobian

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, monte-carlo

- $\vec{X}$ is a vector of random variables in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
- $\rho_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x})$ is probability density of $\vec{X}$.
- $\vec{y} = f(\vec{x})$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$
- $\vec{Y} = f(\vec{X})$ is a vector of random variables in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$
- $\rho_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y})$ is probability density of $\vec{Y}$.
- $m \gt n$

The goal is to find $\rho_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y})$ given $\rho_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x})$ and $f(\vec{x})$.

---

When does the following trick work?

$\rho_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y}) d\vec{y} = \rho_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x}) d\vec{x}$

$\rho_{\vec{Y}}(\vec{y}) \det(\left \lvert J \right \rvert) = \rho_{\vec{X}}(\vec{x})$

For $n = 2, m = 4$, 
$$ J = \left[ \begin{matrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 1 & 0 \\
a_{41} & a_{42} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

where:

- $ a_{ij} = \frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{x_j}} $
- The lower right corner of J is a block of identity matrix
- $\det$ is determinant

---

The [explanation](https://tamaspapp.eu/post/jacobian-chain/) of the trick says it tries to augment the transform from:

$\vec{x} \rightarrow \vec{y}$

to

$(x_{1}, x_{2}, y_{3}, y_{4}) \rightarrow (y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}, y_{4})$

and then integrate the extra dimensions out.

---

What if $\frac{\partial y_{1}(\vec{x})}{\partial{y_3}(\vec{x})} \ne 0$?

If the trick doesn't always work, what is the general method to do this?

---

Update: add an example

Example ([Unit simplex transform](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/reference-manual/simplex-transform-section.html) or [Stick breaking transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process#The_stick-breaking_process))

Let $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{K})$ be a point on the probability simplex:

- $0 \le x_{n} \le 1$
- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + ... x_{K} = 1$

The transformation $\vec{z} = (z_{1}, \ldots, z_{K-1}) = f^{-1}(\vec{x})$ maps from the probability simplex to a hypercube:

- $z_{l} = \log(x_{l}) - \log(x_{l+1} + ... + x_{K})$

For ease of derivation, I define the following:

- Let ${b_{l} = [1 + \exp(z_{l})]^{-1}}$
- Let $c_{l} = 1 - b_{l} = [1 + \exp(-z_{l})]^{-1}$

Then, 
$$ x_{m} = \begin{cases}
c_{1} & \text{if } m = 1 \\
\prod_{l=1}^{K-1} b_{l} & \text{if } m = K \\
c_{m} \prod_{l=1}^{m-1} b_{l} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

For $K = 3$,

$$ J = \left[ \begin{matrix} 
a_{11} & a_{12} & 0  \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & 0  \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 1  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

where $a_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_{i}}{\partial z_j}$

Since $a_{12} = 0$, $ \det(J) = a_{11}a_{22}$

For higher K, only the diagonal terms contribute to the determinant.

$-\log[\det(J)] = \sum_{l=1}^{K-1} (K-l)\log[b_{l}] + \log[c_{l}]$

By testing over many randomly selected values, I verify that the above expression is equivalent to the expression in section "Absolute Jacobian Determinant of the Unit-Simplex Inverse Transform" in [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/reference-manual/simplex-transform-section.html), which mentioned the Jacobian is triangular.

But the manual and [Betancourt 2010](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.752.9226&rep=rep1&type=pdf) didn't say the exact form of the Jacobian ...

Comment: I think the trick as I described didn't always work even when $f$ is bijective. Need to integrate out the extra variables. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Helper_Coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable as you assume, then its image $f(\mathbb R^n)$ will be supported on an (at most $n$-dimensional) submanifold of $\mathbb R^m$. Since the ($m$-dimensional) Lebesgue measure of this submanifold will equal zero, $Y$ will never possess a probability density (with respect to the Lebesgue measure).

As far as I know, there is no general method to address this problem, since probability measures (or random variables) supported on submanifolds of $\mathbb R^m$ are complicated for exactly the above reason. In particular cases, solutions can be found which describe the distribution of $\vec Y$ in other ways than through a probability density.

Update:
In your example, I do not see what $f$, $\vec Y$, $\rho_{\vec X}$ and $\rho_{\vec Y}$ are supposed to be.

Comment: I have self-studied some basic real analysis but I am not familiar enough with Lebesgue measures. I know that Y can have a well-defined probability distribution.

Comment: Not every probability distribution (say on $\mathbb R^n$) possesses a probability density. A probability distribution $\mathbb P\colon \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n) \to [0,1]$ has a probability density $\rho$, if

Comment: for each $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$ we have $$P(A) = \int_A \rho(x)\, \mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Are there general method if $f$ is bijective?

Answer (score 2):

I also originally believe there is no efficient way to deal with the problem. However, by accident, I read some paper on this topic. If the transformation is bijective, there may be some chance.
Basically, the claim is preservation of volume, the $m \times n$ Jacobian
$$ J_f = \frac{\partial Y}{\partial X} $$
If the matrix is full column rank, its volume is 
$$ vol \:J_f = \sqrt{det J_f^T J_f}$$

So, the density function becomes 
$$ \rho_Y \times vol \: J_f = \rho_X
$$

*Ben-Israel, Adi*, [**The change-of-variables formula using matrix volume**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0895479895296896), SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 21, No. 1, 300-312 (1999). [ZBL0955.26007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0955.26007).